# incorrect syntax near keyword select expecting as

Tags: sql

i have following procedure

```
Create procedure Getdatewiseprofitrecord
@Date date
As
Begin
select *into #temptable from(select prof.Productid, SUM(prof.Amount)Amount,SUM(prof.QuantitySold)Quantitysold,SUM(prof.ProfitAmount) from ProfitRecord prof
where prof.Date=@Date
group by Productid)


select temp.*,pro.ProductName from #temptable temp
inner join Productinfo pro on temp.Productid=pro.ProductId

drop table #temptable


End
```

but i get `incorrect syntax near keyword expecting as,id or...`

I could not figure the issue.

Comment: Give your derived table a name and name the columns. `group by Productid) z(a,b,c,d)` Or did you expect SQL Server to think up a name for that fourth column all by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Getdatewiseprofitrecord
@Date DATE
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  * 
INTO    #temptable 
FROM    (SELECT prof.Productid, SUM(prof.Amount) Amount,SUM(prof.QuantitySold) Quantitysold,SUM(prof.ProfitAmount) ProfitAmount 
FROM    ProfitRecord prof
WHERE   prof.Date = @Date
GROUP   BY Productid)

SELECT  temp.*,
        pro.ProductName 
FROM    #temptable temp
JOIN    Productinfo pro on temp.Productid = pro.ProductId

DROP    TABLE #temptable
END
```